# Apache Location Directive is Not Working

Tags: apache-2.2

For some reason I am not able to make the following directive work on my apache. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<Location "/(login.php|register.php)">
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</Location>
```

However following works:

```
<Location "/login.php">
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
     RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use a regular expression, you need `LocationMatch` instead:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#locationmatch

EDIT: should be on ServerFault

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned your apache version however assuming 2.2 or 2.4,
The "~" activates the regex matcher for Location directive.

```
<Location ~ "/(login.php|register.php)">
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</Location>
```

Should work in your case.